# How to Configure freeIPA to host external DNS Zone

Tags: redhat, freeipa

Is it possible to use freeIPA DNS servers to host an external DNS zone that will resolve records for external clients without exposing the internal zones and records?
I need to host SPF and DKIM records and other email related data to the internet without exposing my internal records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, no. If a zone already exists on the net, freeipa isnt having it.

(5 years later I google my own question :-D lol)